# Android, how to prevent internal storage files to be deleted when the app is uninstalled

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I'm developing an app which stores few setting in two .xml files, saved on internal storage. I need to save them in there, so please don't answer me "Save them on SD-cards".

I try to uninstall an then re-install (from Android Studio) my app to see if the `android:allowBackup="true"` works also for internal stored file but the answer was no.

Is this because I done the re-install from the IDE or I need to add some code somewhere?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are all condition of [Backup Schedule](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#BackupSchedule) met?

Comment: internal storage directory is typically - /data/data/your.package.name. Whatever files you create and store in this internal storage directory will be removed when the app is uninstalled as per the Android Developer website - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal 

If you wish to prevent it from deleting even if the app is uninstalled, save them in the primary external storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save those file using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` This stores on the external storage device. Dont get confused with the term external storage as the SD card. SD card is the secondary external storage. But `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns top-level directory of the primary external storage of your device which is basically a non removable storage.

So the file path can be /storage/emulated/0/YOURFOLDER/my.xml

So even if you uninstall the app, these files will not get deleted.

You can use this snippet to create a file in your primary external storage:

```
private final String fileName = "note.txt";    
private void writeFile() {

       File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       // ==> /storage/emulated/0/note.txt
       String path = extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
       Log.i("ExternalStorageDemo", "Save to: " + path);

       String data = editText.getText().toString();

       try {
           File myFile = new File(path);
           myFile.createNewFile();
           FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
           OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
           myOutWriter.append(data);
           myOutWriter.close();
           fOut.close();

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Don't forget to add below permission in Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You can then read that file as below:

```
private void readFile() {

       File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       // ==> /storage/emulated/0/note.txt
       String path = extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
       Log.i("ExternalStorageDemo", "Read file: " + path);

       String s = "";
       String fileContent = "";
       try {
           File myFile = new File(path);
           FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
           BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(fIn));

           while ((s = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
               fileContent += s + "\n";
           }
           myReader.close();

           this.textView.setText(fileContent);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Comment: I create the file with the `openFileOutput()` method like in [this](https://pastebin.com/QXZZ1dGZ) file. How can I use the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method as you suggested?

Comment: @welovelamacompany check my update to write and read file to primary external storage directory

Comment: @welovelamacompany you're welcome. pls do upvote my answer if you found it helpful

Comment: Even the folder Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gets deleted during an uninstall !

Answer (score 3):

Starting API level 29 there is the "hasFragileUserData" manifest flag

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#hasFragileUserData) states that

> If true the user is prompted to keep the app's data on uninstall.
> May be a boolean value, such as "true" or "false".

Sample code:

```
<application
  ....
  android:hasFragileUserData="true">
```